# Spacial Wavefunction Symmetries and Identical particles

Tags: angular-momentum, fermions, orbitals, parity, bosons

I was reading [this](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/752.mf1i.spring03/IdenticalParticlesRevisited.htm) and it mentions in the 3-electron section, that for a spacial wave function to be symmetric under fermion swapping, it must be a function of even parity. Similarly for anti-symmetry under fermion swapping, it must be a function of odd parity.

It is not immediately obvious to me why parity symmetry $(-1)^l$ has anything to do with the bosonic or fermionic properties of the spacial wave function. So I suppose my questions are:

Is it true that spacial inversion is the same symmetry as swapping?

And if so, why?

Comment: parity is what happens when +x is turned to -x, mirror. when you swap you are mirroring.

Comment: think of conservation of parity

Comment: I can see that being the case for say, 2 electrons in an $s$ shell. but if I am swapping 2 electrons, one in $s$ and one in $p$, I see no reason for swapping to be a negation of coordinates, just a trading of coordinates, which may or may not be negating.

Comment: well,   I do not know whether swapping is allowed in this case, so cannot go further into discussion

Comment: @Craig I read the site you're quoting and couldn't find the statement *for a spacial wave function to be symmetric under fermion swapping, it must be a function of even parity*. Would you please tell us where exactly did you find it?

Comment: @ElioFabri My apologies, more specifically: "This is where the  overall (space×spin) antisymmetric wave function for the protons plays a role.  Recall that the parity of a state with rotational angular momentum $l$ is $(−1)^l$. Therefore, para-hydrogen, with an anti-symmetric proton spin wave function, must have a symmetric proton space wave function, and so can only have even values of the rotational angular momentum." It seems to imply that swapping symmetry, and spacial parity symmetry, are the same symmetry.

Comment: @Craig Well, now it's ok. But you can't say *It seems to imply that
swapping symmetry, and spacial parity symmetry, are the same
symmetry.* That's true only for two identical particles in a given
total spin state. Maybe your quotation could continue by noting that
for triplet states only odd values of rotational momentum are allowed.
But in any case you must not confuse two different operations.

Comment: @Craig Swapping particles you exchange all variables, both space and spin. Instead parity only changes *sign* to space coordinates. Also note that for more than two particles things are different - parity is no longer $(-1)^L$, with $L$ total angular momentum. I discussed this point some months ago,
[here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440385/why-is-the-parity-of-the-spatial-wavefunction-1-ell)